# Rounding a float number to 2 decimals to write it to a text file

Tags: c++, file, decimal, precision

I am working on a school project and I have to write a float number to a text file.
The problem is that i only want to write the float number up to 2 decimals to the file.
I searched a lot on the internet but I only found the "setprecision" function for streams.

I can't do that because I don't want to print it but i want to write it to a file with only 2 decimals. So I have to first convert the float number to the same number but with only 2 decimals, then i put it into a string (that already contain other characters). And then I write that string to the output file.

I found in the description of the "ofstream" a method "precision", but I don't think it could work for what I'm trying to do.
(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/)

Does anyone know a function who does that or a manner for doing that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [IO manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) and specifically [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision). Note the examples.

Comment: Files do have a stream API. What's the problem? Yes, it will work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Check the [standard file I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: There is an overwhelming amount of info available on this subject already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't do that because I don't want to print it but i want to write it to a file with only 2 decimals.

ostreams aren't just for printing. You can do the same thing with [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream) as you can do with `cout`.

```
std::ofstream fout("out.txt");

fout << std::setprecision(2) << 1.23456;
```

> That function makes a string that contains the price with the name of the article and the rest of the information I want. The function returns that string and then I write that string to the output file

Well you could write the output by passing an ostream reference to the function instead of getting a string back. You could also have the function just do the formatting when it writes the float into the string. Ostreams aren't just for printing or writing to files:

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << std::setprecision(2) << 1.23456;

std::string s = ss.str();
```

Comment: Thanks bames53! This worked. I tried something like that but didn't knew the "str" method of a stringstream :)

Comment: And if you don't know how many digits are to left of the decimal in your float, `std::setprecision(log10f(x)+3)` where x holds your number.